# Error in Bulk Upload in SQL server from Excel 2007 using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel

I am trying to insert in SQL using Bulk upload. It is working well when I am using from local, even working on Test live URL too. But when I am uploading on Live it breaks after uploading 10000 rows.

Below is my code:

```
public bool ExportExcelToSql (DataTable DT)
    {
        bool result = false;
        tableColumns = "*";
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(_excelConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = null;
                dt = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                _excelSheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                var command = new OleDbCommand("Select " + tableColumns + " FROM [" + _excelSheetName + "]", connection);
                command.CommandTimeout = 6000;
                using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string conString = _sqlConnectionString;
                    var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString);
                    sqlConn.Open();

                    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 6000;
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName.ToString();
                        for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(DT.Rows[i][0].ToString(), DT.Rows[i][1].ToString(),));
                        }
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"? What goes wrong? Does an exception occur? If so, what is the exception message and inner exception (if any)? You haven't provided much detail with respect to your problem other than shown us a bunch of code and ask us to guess what is wrong with it.

Comment: Try uploading smaller chunks (300 rows for example), and commiting them every time it reaches the chunk limit.

Comment: @user1629464 don't bother putting a catch block in your method if all you are going to do in it is throw the exception. doing `throw ex` also actively harms your error handling and diagnosis as it kills the stacktrace.

Comment: No exception and no error message is coming even it works well if I am trying with 10000 rows but when I increase the rows count it fails without any exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the file in chunks and import them one at a time. No, there is no such limit after 100,000 rows. I would suspect that the problem is that the file does not match the format file or that your using something like SQL Express 2008 R2 is limited to 4GB database size.

Comment: I checked nothing wrong with the file format. When I delete some rows it works. Works till 10k rows. When I am trying with 50k rows it fails without any exception.